# How to call the MsgBox Function

Tags: vba, ms-word, msgbox

How do I “Call” Vba’s MsgBox function? Is this the same as just using the actual function itself? I want to make a MsgBox function that returns the date and time.

Comment: Did you look it up in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function)?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
MsgBox "It is now " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn"), vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Current Date and Time"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the same as just using the actual function itself ?

Yes, you may consider it as a regular function in VBA.

> I want to make a MsgBox function that returns the date and time

The [MsgBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function) function is for displaying questions or warnings and etc. to users and returning answers like `Yes`, `No`, `Cancel` and etc. Strictly speaking the function displays a message in a dialog box, waits for the user to click a button, and returns an `Integer` indicating which button the user clicked.

If you need to let users enter any information on on the dialog box you need to use the [InputBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function) function instead. It displays a prompt in a dialog box, waits for the user to input text or click a button, and returns a `String` containing the contents of the text box. You may then parse the date entered on the dialog box and use it in the code. For example:

```
Dim Message, Title, Default, MyValue
Message = "Enter a value between 1 and 3"    ' Set prompt.
Title = "InputBox Demo"    ' Set title.
Default = "1"    ' Set default.
' Display message, title, and default value.
MyValue = InputBox(Message, Title, Default)

' Display dialog box at position 100, 100.
MyValue = InputBox(Message, Title, Default, 100, 100)
```